# SQL avoid empty rows

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Is there a way to avoid empty rows in a SQL statement?
My output is:

```
a    | b   | c
1      2     3
4
EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY
5
```

But i want:

```
a | b | c
1   2   3
4
5
```

Comment: `where a<>'EMPTY' && b<>'EMPTY' && c<> 'EMPTY'`? or whatever?

Comment: is it the text empty or null?  if null indicate `where a is not null and b is not null and c is not null`  but to know for sure we would need to see sample data and expected results and your current query.  There may be  away to eliminate the nulls/empty do to something wrong in the current query.  Such as an outer join and columns ABC are coming from the table returning only matched records. maybe an inner join should be used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value is empty or if it is `null` are two different things so I am unsure which you are looking for.

**If NULL**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a IS NOT NULL OR b IS NOT NULL OR c IS NOT NULL;
```

**If empty**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a <> '' OR b <> '' OR c <> '';
```

Comment: take this one step farther and show how you can use ISNULL() or COALESE() to compare empty & null at the same time.  WHERE COALESCE(a,'') <> '' AND ....

Comment: @maplemale I am in agreement with duncan on AND.  But duncan I just re-read your answer I must of blanked why are you using and is NOT null instead of IS NULL? That would drop everythign except row 1 off.  I think you meant to use a IS NULL AND b IS NULL and c IS NULL

Comment: I agree with maplemale: the query should use `OR`. When using `AND` it will only return `(1,2,3)` but not `(4,null,null)`

Comment: @maplemale You are correct after looking at the question again. I apologize editing now.

Comment: Yes it is OR if using IS NOT NULL, but it is AND if using IS NULL

Comment: @Matt

AND would exclude rows where any column is NULL/blank. The request is to include those rows where some columns are null (or blank) and some aren't. So, OR should be used regardless of whether ISNULL is used or not. There is no need for AND in this case at all as it would make it exclusive instead of inclusive. Does that make sense? The only way you could use AND is to re-arrange the query to have an exclusive piece with a NOT similar to the way a_horse_with_no_name's answer reads. So, WHERE NOT(a IS NULL and b IS NULL and C IS NULL)

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to check all columns of the table use this:

```
select *
from the_table
where not (the_table is null);
```

This will remove all rows where all columns are null.

If you just want to check a subset of the columns (e.g. because there is a generated PK column that you didn't show us), use:

```
select *
from the_table
where not ( (a,b,c) is null);
```

Comment: Side question: Which does the optimizer like more? An exclusive AND operator with a NOT or inclusive OR operators? Or, does it not make a difference? From a pure readability option, I like the where not ( (a,b,c) is null) answer better than the accepted answer just from a readability standpoint. But, maybe it's syntactical sugar?